# Query with subquery is not updateable. Is there a work-around?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, recordset

I'm working with a database in Microsoft Access, and this is the scenario I'm trying to find a solution for:

Companies send in applications to apply for more capacity. The application can contain multiple smaller capacities which add up to the total capacity of the application. The applications are stored in the table tApplication and the capacities associated with the application are stored in tCapacity.

I wish to present information about the application including the total capacity. Therefore I have a form with the following Data Source:

```
SELECT tApplication.ID,tApplication.CompanyID, tApplication.statusID,
(SELECT SUM(tCapacity.Capacity) FROM tCapacity WHERE tApplication.ID = tCapacity.ApplicationID) AS TotalCapacity
FROM tApplication;
```

This query gives me the information I need, but it hinders me from edit anything in the recordset (Using subqueries apparently makes your query not updateable in Microsoft Access). Is there a way around this? I've been playing around with the idea to store the applications and capacities in the same table, but I'm not sure it's a good design choice.

Comment: Options: 1) DSum() domain aggregate function in query or textbox; 2) subform; 3) listbox.

Comment: display the 2nd table in a sub form - after all, that looks to be the data that is to be added or changed. So your main form can display the information, but in a sub form you can display the rows of the child table for editing or adding new rows.

Comment: Post the solution that you found as an answer and also accept it so it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used DSUM() which worked great. Thank you to June7.

```
SELECT tApplication.ID,tApplication.CompanyID, tApplication.statusID,
DSUM( "tCapacity.Capacity" , "tCapacity", "tCapacity.ApplicationID = " & tApplication.ID) AS TotalCapacity
FROM tApplication;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this two options:

**Make Table Queries**
Make-Table queries are just like Select queries except their results are put into a new table rather than a datasheet view. You specify the table name and it is created. If the table exists, it is replaced. To create a Make-Table query, open the query (qryCustomerSales) in design mode, and choose Make-Table Query from the Query menu

**Use Append Queries Rather than Make-Table Queries**
An alternative to Make-Table queries is an Append query. Append queries let you insert records from a query into an existing table. If you just have a one step process, there usually is not much difference. However, if you have multiple steps, Append queries have a clear advantage.

More information:
https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html#Example2